# Minimum number of squares to tile the rectanlge in C

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

The task:

Assume a rectangle of size n × m. Determine the minimum number of squares that
is required to tile the rectangle.

I tried the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int matrix(int n, int m)
{
    int dp[n+1][m+1];

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=m;j++)
        {
            dp[i][j] = INFINITY;
        }
    }

    return MinSquare(n, m, dp);
}

int MinSquare(int n, int m, int dp[n][m])
{
    int horizontalMin = INFINITY;
    int verticalMin = INFINITY;

    if(n==m)
    {
        dp[m][n] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    if(dp[n][m] != INFINITY)
    {
        return dp[n][m];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        verticalMin = MIN(MinSquare(i,m,dp)+ MinSquare(n-i,m,dp), horizontalMin);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        horizontalMin = MIN(MinSquare(n,i,dp)+MinSquare(n,m-i,dp), horizontalMin);
    }
    dp[n][m] = MIN(verticalMin, horizontalMin);

    return dp[n][m];
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", matrix(3,4));
    return 0;
}
```

This results in 2147483647 and I don't see why my code doesn't run correctly.

Any hints?

Comment: Another problem is that you call `MinSquare` recursively, changing the value of `m` and `n`. This doesn't work because the third argument depends on `m`. I'm surprised there's no warning from the compiler!\

Comment: The algorithm looks too simple. In the site [there](https://leetcode.com/problems/tiling-a-rectangle-with-the-fewest-squares/), they ask the same question but also give some examples. The algorithm here will not solve the most complicated example there.

Comment: @anatolyg You're right -- if correctly implemented, this algorithm would solve the problem if you require every cut goes all the way across a piece.

Comment: I don't see why the squares can be bigger than the rectangles. Since in one iteration m is fixed while the other is variable and in the second iteration the other way around.

Comment: I made an edit and it seems to work now.

Comment: You still have the problem that your array accesses are all over the place because `dp` is of type `int[n+1][m+1]` but as a parameter to your function it's declared as a VLA of type `int *dp[m]` (with a type that's dependent on the argument `m` which varies). For example `matrix(10, 3)` produces the wrong result.

Comment: Please do not edit the question in ways that invalidate existing answers. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. It is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers that serves other readers in the future. They should find a clearly posed question and answers to it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did a rollback just as you typed that.

Comment: @Lundin: I was thinking of rolling back to version 1, since version 2 removed the `INFINITY` that an answer addresses (albeit incorrectly).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah yeah that's true. Will fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two grave problems. There are probably more than that, but these give you a good start.

#### Problem 1

`INFINITY` is a special value for `float`. The C standard does not define the behavior of assigning `int anyIntVar = INFINITY`, and it should not be used.

A possible fix is to use `INT_MAX` (defined in `<limits.h>`) instead of `INFINITY`.

#### Problem 2

```
verticalMin = MIN(MinSquare(i,m,dp)+ MinSquare(n-i,m,dp), horizontalMin);
```

should be

```
verticalMin = MIN(MinSquare(i,m,dp)+ MinSquare(n-i,m,dp), verticallMin);
```

Comment: Per C 2018 6.3.1.4 1, conversion of floating-point infinity to an integer type has undefined behavior; it is not required to produce `INT_MAX`.

Comment: The fact the behavior is undefined does not mean the conversion produces a result whose value is unspecified. It means the entire behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. It not only does not necessarily produce a particular result, but the program may abort, or it may continue execution with wrong results in other operations, or it may execute entirely different code. On an execution path in which there is undefined behavior, the C standard imposes **no requirements** on the behavior of the program, none at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, I reworded that.

Comment: The sentence “Therefore, the following check is always true.” is incorrect. Because the behavior of the program is no longer defined after the conversion of `INFINITY` to an integer type, the C standard would permit the following check to evaluate as true.